# protoc error in hadoop in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, protoc

When I build hadoop source code I am getting following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.7.2:protoc (execution: compile-protoc, phase: generate-sources)    pom.xml /hadoop-common  line 335    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

here is my pom

```
</execution>
          <execution>
            <id>compile-protoc</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>protoc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <protocVersion>${protobuf.version}</protocVersion>
              <protocCommand>${protoc.path}</protocCommand>
              <imports>
                <param>${basedir}/src/main/proto</param>
              </imports>
              <source>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/proto</directory>
                <includes>
                  <include>HAServiceProtocol.proto</include>
                  <include>IpcConnectionContext.proto</include>
                  <include>ProtocolInfo.proto</include>
                  <include>RpcHeader.proto</include>
                  <include>ZKFCProtocol.proto</include>
                  <include>ProtobufRpcEngine.proto</include>
                  <include>Security.proto</include>
                  <include>GetUserMappingsProtocol.proto</include>
                  <include>TraceAdmin.proto</include>
                  <include>RefreshAuthorizationPolicyProtocol.proto</include>
                  <include>RefreshUserMappingsProtocol.proto</include>
                  <include>RefreshCallQueueProtocol.proto</include>
                  <include>GenericRefreshProtocol.proto</include>
                </includes>
              </source>
              <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</output>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev
```